# Python tkinter module text transitioning

Tags: python, animation, text, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I just started Python a few days ago, and I have gotten to animations. I am working on one called "Bounce!", and it has that name on the screen, with other settings. The settings are FPS and Speed (increment). But, as an oval bounces, these settings change, and I want the text to change along with it, but I do not know how. This is my current code:

```
import time
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
fps=30
increment=2
canvas = Canvas(tk,height='500',width='500')
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_oval(175,100,325,250,fill='red',outline='black')
canvas.create_line(50,100,450,100)
canvas.create_line(50,450,450,450)
canvas.create_text(250,30,text='Bounce!',fill='red',font=('Consolas',30))
x = canvas.create_text(250,75,text=('FPS: %s; Speed: %s'% (fps,increment)),fill='black',font=('Consolas',20)) #mainproblem

while True:
    increment += 1
    if increment % 2 == 0 and fps > 1:
        fps = fps - 1
    #I want the 'x' text to change to the current FPS and Speed here, but I do not know how.
    for x in range(0, int(200/increment)):
        canvas.move(1,0,increment)
        tk.update()
        time.sleep(1/fps)
    for x in range(0, int(200/increment)):
        canvas.move(1,0,-(increment))
        tk.update()
        time.sleep(1/fps)
```

I am using Python 3.4.2.

Comment: tkinter isn't designed to be used this way -- in general you should never call `sleep` in a gui, nor have your own infinite loop.  There are, I think, several questions and answers about doing animation in tkinter on this site, and all all revolve around running mainloop and calling `after` to run functions periodically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
fps=30
increment=2
t = ('FPS: %s; Speed: %s'% (fps,increment))
canvas = Canvas(tk,height='500',width='500')
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_oval(175,100,325,250,fill='red',outline='black')
canvas.create_line(50,100,450,100)
canvas.create_line(50,450,450,450)
canvas.create_text(250,30,text='Bounce!',fill='red',font=('Consolas',30))
w = canvas.create_text(250,75,text= t,fill='black',font=('Consolas',20)) #mainproblem

while True:
    increment += 1
    if increment % 2 == 0 and fps > 1:
        fps = fps - 1
    t = ('FPS: %s; Speed: %s'% (fps,increment))

    canvas.itemconfig(w, text= t)

    for x in range(0, int(200/increment)):
        canvas.move(1,0,increment)
        tk.update()
        time.sleep(1/fps)
    for x in range(0, int(200/increment)):
        canvas.move(1,0,-(increment))
        tk.update()
        time.sleep(1/fps)
```

Comment: At least provide a minimum description as to how to fix the problem, so one does not have to compare the entire code, character by character, with the original.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itemconfigure` to change the settings of elements on the canvas (see [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas-methods.html)). Also note that your loop variable `x` is shadowing the variable you assigned the ID of the text to.

```
text = canvas.create_text(...)
    ...
    canvas.itemconfigure(text, text=('FPS: %s; Speed: %s'% (fps,increment)))
```